# отрицательное число в индексах

Tags: c++

Oбычно в индексах массивов, контейнеров используется беззнаковое число. К тому же `unsigned(-1)` компилятором преобразовывается на большое положительное число
Так почему же в индексах отрицательное число дает не такой эффект? 
Например:

```
int n[] = {1, 2, 3 };
int* pn = &n[1];
if (n - (&n[-1]) == 1)
    std::cout << pn[-1]; // выведет n[1 - 1] т.е. n[0]
```

или

```
std::vector<int>::end()[-1]
```

то же, что

```
std::vector<int>::back();
```

Comment: потому что для указателей `pn[-1]`, `*(pn-1)` и даже `(-1)[pn]` — это полностью идентичные конструкции... С вектором надо посмотреть, что именно там... скорей всего итератор неявно преобразуется в указатель, указывающий за последний элемент и соответственно это, UB.

Comment: не думаю, что итератор преобразуется в указатель.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Все стает просто, если знать, что конструкция `a[b]` - это всего навсего `*(a+b)`. Поэтому, выражение

```
int* pn = &n[1];
```

преобразуется в

```
int* pn = &(*(n+1));
int* pn = n+1;
```

и потом выражение

```
pn[-1]
```

преобразуется в `*(pn-1)` => `*(n+1-1)` => `*(n+0)` => `n[0]`.

Аналогично расскрывается и выражение `n - (&n[-1])`.

В случае вектора компилятор может итератор заменить на указатель и наблюдается та же история. Но как только компилятор чуточку сделает по другому (а он имеет право), может получится все, что угодно.

Comment: В случае вектора возвращаемый итератор соответствует спецификации итератора случайного доступа и реализует оператор индексирования с аналогичным поведением.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan `std::random_access_iterator_tag` тут не при чем. Оператор индексирования обязан быть только у итераторов произвольного доступа, а попытка его вызова у однонаправленного  итератора (у того же std::list) может просто привести к ошибке компиляции.

Comment: я в стандарте нашел только в векторе упоминая о `then it obeys the identity &v[n] == &v[0] + n for all 0 <= n < v.size().` то есть, индекст ноль или больше

Comment: @VTT, вы правы, я извеняюсь,  наверное переработал -  башка не варит...

Comment: @ KoVadim, все ясно, спасибо за внимание и   полный ответ

Answer (score 3):

Параметр оператора `[]` стандартного контейнера, как вы правильно заметили, имеет беззнаковый тип. Соответственно аргумент такого оператора при вызове будет приводиться к беззнаковому типу.

Параметр *встроенного* оператора `[]` не имеет беззнакового типа и не приводится к беззнаковому типу. Встроенный оператор `[]` прекрасно умеет работать и с отрицательными значениями, пока вы соблюдаете правила адресной арифметики языка.

(В целях overload resolution, [встроенный оператор `[]` рассматривается как имеющий параметр типа `std::ptrdiff_t`](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.built#16), который является знаковым)

Правила адресной арифметики говорят, что адресная арифметика в С и С++ поддерживается только среди элементов одного массива. Соответственно отрицательные индексы в `[]` могут быть использованы только в том случае, если доступ осуществляется относительно указателя, указывающего куда-то "в середину" существующего  массива.

В вашем примере кода выражение `pn[-1]` удовлетворяет этим правилам, а в выражении `n[-1]` это правило нарушено. Выражение `n[-1]` порождает неопределенное поведение. Код формально неработоспособен.

---

Выражение вида `some_vector.end()[-1]` формально некорректно. К итератору контейнера в общем случае вообще не применим оператор `[]`. Скомпилироваться такое выражение может только случайно за счет того, что в некоторой реализации 
итераторы `std::vector` оказались реализованы как обычные "голые" указатели.

Попыткой создания корректной формы такого выражения может быть  `(&*some_vector.end())[-1]`, т.е. преобразование итератора в "голый" указатель, и последующее применение к нему оператора `[]`. Но в таком случае мы применяем оператор `*` к итератору `some_vector.end()`, что порождает неопределенное поведение.

Так что пытаться индексироваться "назад" от `end()` итератора при помощи опратора `[]` - плохая идея. Пользуйтесь для этого `std::next`/`std::prev`.

Comment: @ AnT,  я у Страуструпа прочитал шаблонную функцию  template <class Ran... >  //...  (Ran first, Ran last) { //... if (  *first  <= last[ - 1]  ) //... }, что  кажется противоречит вашему первому предложению, а в остальном все понятно. Что вы на это скажете?  Спасибо!...

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Не совсем понимаю, где вы тут видите противоречие. Очевидно, данная шаблонная  функция предназначена для работы с обыкновенными "голыми" *указателями* `first` и `last`. То есть оператор `[]` в этом случае никакого отношения к стандартным контейнерам не имеет и никакого приведения к беззнаковому типу тут никак не замешано.

Comment: @ AnT,  ну или я вас неправильно понел или я вам неправильно изложил свои мысли -  но  в целом  для меня все понятно теперь, и это самое главное, поскольку вы смогли мне помочь с выяснением интересующего мне вопроса, потому еще раз спасибо!

Comment: `*(some_vector.end() - 1)` - разве нет?